# I am getting two run-time errors while running below mentioned VBA code

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting the following error "Run-time error '1004' Application-defined or object defined error and highlighting the following line of code 
*newb.sheets(shts(s)).Range("a1").Resize(, cols).Value = wb.sheets(shts(s)).Range(heds(s)).Value*

When I skip the above line of code and move to the next one it is showing another error "Run-time error '9' script out of range" and highlighting the following line of code 
*"newb.sheets(shts(s)).Range("a" & rw(s)).Resize(rws, cols).Value = wb.sheets(s).Range(Rng(s) & rws - 1).Value" Please help me what to do.*

Can someone please help me to fix above mentioned errors?

```
 Sub Consolidation()

 Dim newb as workbook
 Dim wb as workbook
 Dim Shts
 Dim rws as long
 Dim rw(2) As Long
 mypath = "C:\Consolidation\"
 shts = Array("Total Consolidation", "State level Consolidation", "District Level Consolidation")

 Set newb = Workbooks.Add
 newb.Sheets(1).Name = shts(0)
 newb.Sheets(2).Name = shts(1)
 newb.Sheets(3).Name = shts(2)

 rw(0) = 1
 rw(1) = 1
 rw(2) = 1

 rng = Array("a6:k", "a2:g", "o2:aa")
 cols = Array("11", "7", "13")
 heds = Array("a1:k1", "a1:g1", "o1:aa1")
 fname = Dir(mypath & "*.xls")

 Do While Len(fname) > 0
     Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(mypath & fname)
 For s = 0 To 2
     rws = Wb.Sheets(shts(s)).UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1

If s = 0 Then rws = rws - 6

If Not headsdone Then
    newb.Sheets(shts(s)).Range("a1").Resize(, cols(s)).value = Wb.Sheets(shts(s)).Range(heds(s)).value
    headsdone = True
End If

newb.Sheets(shts(s)).Range("a" & rw(s)).Resize(rws, cols(s)).value = Wb.Sheets(shts(s)).Range(rng(s) & rws).value

rw(s) = rw(s) + rws - 1

Next

fname = Dir

Loop

newb.SaveAs mypath & "COUNTRY LEVEL CONSOLIDATION.xls"

newb.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: What is `rng(s) & rws - 1` supposed to be doing? seems odd that you would be making a range address in this fashion.

Comment: also can you do something like `dim rightSide as vaiant, leftSide as vaiant: set rightSide = Wb.Sheets(shts(s)).Range(heds(s)): set leftSide = newb.Sheets(shts(s)).Range("a1").Resize(, cols)`. What are `leftSide` and `rightSide` equal to?

Comment: Those are the rows range in three worksheets that need to be copied

Comment: The objects are successfully being set then?

Comment: I am currently having 55 workbooks in a folder (ex. “C:\Consolidation”) and each workbook contains 11 worksheets.

In that I need to consolidate the following three sheets 1. Total Consolidation, 2. State level Consolidation and 3. District Level Consolidation from all 55 workbooks and save it in three different sheets in a new workbook in the same folder (i.e. C:\Consolidation).

Comment: Yes.  So now macro should open one workbook at a time and copy three worksheets separately and paste them including the heading (heading should be copied only for the 1st workbook and second workbook onwards no need to copy the headings) into three worksheets in a new workbook named as “COUNTRLY LEVEL CONSOLIDATION”.

Comment: @vbalearner: I am assuming that you cannot see my answer? You may want to refresh the page?

Comment: For "Total Consolidation" sheet it should copy from row A6 to K6 and till the last row where data exists
for "State level Consolidation" sheet it should copy from A1 to G1 and till the last row where data exists
for "District Level Consolidation" sheet it should copy from O1 to AA1 and till the last row where data exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that error because of `Cols` in `Resize(, cols)` . `Cols` is an array and not an `Integer/Long` Value.

```
cols = Array("11", "7", "13")
```

What you want is to pick up a value from the array like `Cols(0)` so that it picks up either the `11` or `7` or the `13`

For example

```
newb.Sheets(shts(s)).Range("a1").Resize(, cols(0)).value
```

Comment: Thanks.  Let me check this.

Comment: When I use numbers 7, 11 or 13, I am getting another error "Subscript out of range.  Also if I put Cols(s) or Cols(0) no data being copied from the source sheet to new sheet

Comment: You are getting `Subscript out of range` because Excel cannot find the relevant object. For example `Sheets(shts(s))`. Ensure the sheet name matches with the actual sheet name. Ensure that there are no unwanted spaces etc...

Comment: I am completely lost.  I have checked the names of the sheets several times and everything is file, but still I am getting this error.

Comment: During the step through process, when I place the cursor on the code, it is showing the names correctly, but data not being copied into the new sheets.

Comment: We will come to that. What about the `Subscript out of range` error?

Comment: When I put Cols(0), it is taking columns correctly and I don't see subscript out of range error

Comment: ok so that part is solved. :) Now your next query is that the data is not being copied. correct?

Comment: Also another line of code having error "newb.Sheets(shts(s)).Range("a" & rw(s)).Resize(rws, cols).value = Wb.Sheets(s).Range(rng(s) & rws - 1).value"

Comment: What is the value of `(shts(s)` , `rw(s)` and `rws` when you get the error? Also Like I said `cols` is an array and not long. You are again using `cols`

Comment: Shall I explain in detail about what macro should do?  and How it should consolidate data?

Comment: Sure. I would recommend updating your question with the actual requirement and provide a ling to few snapshots if possible. Tha would ensure speedy solution providing. :) I would be stepping out for couple of hours. will have a look when I come back. I promise :)

Comment: I am seeing the values for (shts(s) it is showing as "Total Consolidation" and rw(s) it showing the value as 1, for Cols(0) it is showing the value as 11, but still I am getting "Script Out of Range" error

Comment: Please find my detail description below.

Comment: Dear Siddarth,  I have been trying this code from past 3 days, but still couldn't able to run it.  Could you please help me and correct the code?

Comment: I could able to find the problem in the two lines.  The correct code should be:  `newb.sheets(shts(s)).Range("a1").Resize(, cols(s)).Value = wb.sheets(shts(s)).Range(heds(s)).Value`   `newb.sheets(shts(s)).Range("a" & rw(s)).Resize(rws, cols).Value = wb.sheets(shts(s)).Range(Rng(s) & rws - 1).Value`

Comment: Also these #N/As are counting as rows, so when next sheet data will be copied below these #N/A values which means for every sheet we see #N/As in 6 rows. This is for first sheet.  For 2nd & 3rd sheets, one #N/A row being added.  Is there a way to avoid these #N/As?

Comment: Dear Siddharth,I have accepted your question, since your answer actually helped me to find the errors in the code.  **It would be great if you could help me to fix those #N/A errors**

Comment: Ok I am back. Sorry, like I mentioned I was going out and I did promise that I will be back. So here I am :)

Comment: Wow that are lot of comments.I would recommend deleting all these comments and rephrasing your actual question will all these details :)

Comment: Hi Siddharth,  I could able to fix most of the problmes in the code, but one last thing for which I am unable to fix it.  The problem is only for 1st sheet, macro is copying the headings everytime and for other two sheet it is not at all copying the headings.  What I want is it should copy headings only for the first time for every sheet and second time onwards it should not copy headings.  Could you please help me on this?

Comment: Sure. Can you update the question with the latest code that you are using? Also can you delete the extra comments above as it clutters the comments :)

Answer (score 0):

I could able to fix all errors.  Please find the final code below.

```
 Sub consolidation()

 Dim newb As Workbook
 Dim wb As Workbook
 Dim rws As Long
 Dim shts
 Dim rw(2) As Long
 Dim s As Integer

 mypath = "C:\Consolidation\"
 shts = Array("Total Consolidation", "State level Consolidation", "District Level Consolidation")
 Set newb = Workbooks.Add

 newb.sheets(1).Name = shts(0)
 newb.sheets(2).Name = shts(1)
 newb.sheets(3).Name = shts(2)

 rw(0) = 1
 rw(1) = 1
 rw(2) = 1

 Rng = Array("a7:k", "a2:g", "o2:aa")
 cols = Array("11", "7", "13")
 heds = Array("a6:k6", "a1:g1", "o1:aa1")
 fname = Dir(mypath & "*.xls")

 Do While Len(fname) > 0
 Set wb = Workbooks.Open(mypath & fname)
 For s = 0 To 2
 rws = wb.sheets(shts(s)).UsedRange.Rows.Count

 Headsdone = True

 If Headsdone Then
    newb.sheets(shts(s)).Range("a1").Resize(, cols(s)).Value = wb.sheets(shts(s)).Range(heds(s)).Value
 End If

 If s = 0 Then
 newb.sheets(shts(s)).Range("a" & rw(s) + 1).Resize(-6 + rws, cols(s)).Value = wb.sheets(shts(s)).Range(Rng(s) & rws).Value
 rw(s) = rw(s) + rws - 6
 End If

 If s = 1 Then
 newb.sheets(shts(s)).Range("a" & rw(s) + 1).Resize(-1 + rws, cols(s)).Value = wb.sheets(shts(s)).Range(Rng(s) & rws).Value
 rw(s) = rw(s) + rws - 1
 End If

 If s = 2 Then
 newb.sheets(shts(s)).Range("a" & rw(s) + 1).Resize(-1 + rws, cols(s)).Value = wb.sheets(shts(s)).Range(Rng(s) & rws).Value
 rw(s) = rw(s) + rws - 1
 End If

 Next

 wb.Close False
 fname = Dir

 Loop
 newb.SaveAs mypath & "COUNTRY LEVEL CONSOLIDATION.xlsx"

 newb.Close

 End Sub
```